# dice game in java (calling from a class with a constructor)

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I'm trying to make a dice game with a dice that can give a random number between 1 to 6.
 I have a class that is called Die which consist of one constructor and two methods. 
 The constructors main purpose is to initiate a random value and the two methods should roll the dice and return the value respectively. 
    My problem is that I don't know how to roll the dice and retrieve the number after I have made an object.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Die{
    int dots,roll;
    Random number = new Random();

    public Die(){
        int dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;
    }

    public void roll(){
        roll = number.nextInt(dots)+1;
    }

    public int getDots(){
        return roll;
    }

}

public class Uppg1 {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Die die = new Die();
        System.out.println("Du fick "+die.getDots());

    }
}
```

It appears that my code goes to the constructor and not to methods. I want the value from the constructor and then roll the dice and then get the value from method getDots.

Comment: `int dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;` creates a local variable called *dots*, the actual field `dots` is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `Die` constructor you update internal `dots` variable instead of class member.
Use:

```
public Die(){
    dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;
```

This is different variable from the variable

```
class Die{
    int dots,roll;
```

so make it

```
dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;
```

so that you will get the right value.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code for you just take a look:import java.util.Random;

```
class Die{
    int dots,roll;
    Random number = new Random();

    public Die(){
         dots = number.nextInt(6)+1 ;
    }

    public void roll(){
        roll = number.nextInt(dots)+1;
    }

    public int getDots(){

        return roll;
    }

}

public class Uppg1 {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Die die = new Die();
        die.roll();
        System.out.println("Du fick" +die.getDots());

    }
}
```

remove int from Die constructor as it already defined as global,
your prog. doesn't call roll method anywhere hence need to call that.

Answer (score 1):

`int dots = number.nextInt(6)+1` does not change the field `dots` but creates a new variable `dots`

Additionally you never call `roll()` so `roll=null` and `getDots()` returns null.

You can roll the dice by calling `die.roll()` in the Uppg1 main method.